# how to insert ".png" images in textcell at Google Colaboratory?

Tags: image, google-colaboratory

png" files in text cell.

so I Interlock my google dirve and then

```
![iris]("drive/GPU/data/iris.PNG")
```

but it is not showed.

please teach me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
![iris](drive/GPU/data/iris.PNG)
```

Or from python

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename="drive/GPU/data/iris.PNG")
```